# Converting build.xml to build.groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, ant

I am trying to convert build.xml (which is used in my project for Ant) completely into a Groovy script by eliminating the Build.xml completely.

Bascially, what I am trying to achieve is Build.xml ---> Build.groovy.

I have below queries while attempting to do so.

1) How to translate macrodef into a function in my groovy script

```
<macrodef name="build.record">
         <attribute name="log.file"/>
         <attribute name="action"/>
         <sequential>
                 <echo message="starting build4.record with file name @{log.file} and action @{action}" />
                 <record name="@{log.file}" action="@{action}" loglevel="verbose" />
         </sequential>
     </macrodef>
```

I know sequentional can be achieve by using groovy.util.AntBuilder.sequential How to convert the macrodef as a whole into groovy function in my script?

2) How to create Ant JavaDoc  in my groovy script?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are aware of Gradle as a build tool, which uses Groovy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like that?
 ( you can do it in million ways.. )

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

def buildRecord={Map attr->
    ant.echo(message: "starting build4.record with file name ${attr['log.file']} and action ${attr.action}" )
    ant.record(name: "${attr['log.file']}", action: "${attr.action}", loglevel:"verbose" )
}

ant.echo(message:"start")
buildRecord('log.file': "myfile", action: "myaction")
ant.javadoc(sourcepath: "...", "destdir": "...")
```

and checkout the [gradle](http://gradle.org) build tool where you can write in groovy with using AntBuilder like above